How to use variable instead of giving field in filter queryset django
if I have a class like this:
class Name: field1 = ... field2 = ... ... 
I do not know what are the fields or model it should be given by user so key is going to be name of field in a model and value is what should I look for that.
and base on some if I have to filter them with field1 or 2 and I have them from input in variables?
if name is an instance of Name and if key = field1 and value='example_to_look' ,I want
name.objects.filter(key=value) not name.objects.filter(field1=value)
i want to use this on different classes and fields so if is not what I want.
raw() always triggers a new query and doesn’t account for previous filtering but I need them all and I have to filter one by one!

It is still not completely clear to me. Your Name has two fields? Can you perhaps add some example with the expected behavior?

What are key and value here?.. Are you looking for django.db.models.Q combinable?

it is may have more field . I have no clue about model and fields, it should do query dynamic @willem-van-onsem

@STerliakov no I have no clue what are model, fields and values and users gonna give it to me

we have to create a dict like do_filter={key:value} then use query_set =model.objects.all() then query_set.filter(**do_filter) for each one:)
this way you can dynamically generate our query_set base on given variables.
